# Problem with script that is suppose to add two numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, addition

I wrote up a code designed to add two numbers and it keeps returning a NaN when I ask for an answer, I am fairly new but would like to know why this code in particular does not work so I can make sure I don't make the mistake again.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>April23</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Top Portion-->
<div class="container1">

    <div class="calculator">
<label for="num1" id="num1">Enter First Number </label>
<input type="text" id="number0" name=num1 size=10>  
</div>
<div class="calculator">
<label for="num2" id="num2">Enter Second Number</label>
<input type="text" id="number1" name=num1 size=10>  
</div>

<div class="calculator2" id="button">
        <button id="btn">Get Result</button>
        </div>


<div class="calculator">
    <label for="num2" id="sum"> Sum   </label>
    <input type="text" id="number" name=num1 size=10>   
    </div>
    
    



</div>

<div class="container1" id="c2"></div>
<div class="container1"></div>





</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
/*this portion is to check if the blank input boxes are filled or not*/
const num1 = document.querySelector('#number0');
const num2 = document.querySelector('#number1');

/*this portion is to grab the value of the input boxes if they are filled*/
var number1=document.getElementById("number0").value;
var number2=document.getElementById("number1").value;

/*this portion is to convert the values into integers*/
x = parseInt(number1);
y = parseInt(number2);

const calc = document.querySelector(".calculator2");





calc.addEventListener('click', (e)=>
{ 

    e.preventDefault();
if(num1.value===''  || num2.value ===''){
    alert('please enter both numbers');
}
else{

    
   alert(x+y);
}

}
)
```

So the first condition works and sends an alert box asking to input two numbers, the second condition returns a an Alert box with NaN instead of adding the two numbers

css

```
body{
margin: 0;;
/*background: url('image0.jpg') no-repeat;  ;*/
font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
background-color: thistle;


}


.container1{
position: relative;  
height: 50vh;
background: rgb(39, 105, 160);
opacity: 0.9;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

justify-content: center;
gap: 2rem;

}

.calculator{
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

#number{
    margin-left: 7.5rem;
}
#number0{
margin-left: 1rem;
}




#c2{

    background-color: rgb(196, 169, 169);
}

.calculator2{
    margin-left: 4rem;
}
```

Comment: Grab the numbers from the input boxes on click, not before the click occurs. Grabbing the values from the inputs before the click will give you empty strings, which when parsed gives `NaN`

Comment: Thanks,I did not know that. Does that apply if I designate x and y as const values as well?

Comment: Yes, if you make them `const` all that will mean (other than scoping differences) is that you can't re-assign them later (eg: do `x = <something>` later on in your code). The issue is mainly to do with `x` and `y` holding empty strings (`''`), which when you do `parseInt('')` gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the number after you click on the button not before. Everything else is great.

**TIP:** As you are adding the number there must be always a type number so it would be better to add `type="number"` on `input` so that the user cannot enter alphabets or special characters.

```js
const calc = document.querySelector(".calculator2");

calc.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = document.querySelector("#number0").value;
  const y = document.querySelector("#number1").value;

  if (x === "" || y === "") {
    alert("please enter both numbers");
  } else {
    alert(parseInt(x) + parseInt(y));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  ;
  /*background: url('image0.jpg') no-repeat;  ;*/
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  background-color: thistle;
}

.container1 {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgb(39, 105, 160);
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.calculator {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

#number {
  margin-left: 7.5rem;
}

#number0 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#c2 {
  background-color: rgb(196, 169, 169);
}

.calculator2 {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="calculator">
    <label for="num1" id="num1">Enter First Number </label>
    <input type="number" id="number0" name=num1 size=10>
  </div>
  <div class="calculator">
    <label for="num2" id="num2">Enter Second Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="number1" name=num1 size=10>
  </div>

  <div class="calculator2" id="button">
    <button id="btn">Get Result</button>
  </div>


  <div class="calculator">
    <label for="num2" id="sum"> Sum </label>
    <input type="text" id="number" name=num1 size=10>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container1" id="c2"></div>
<div class="container1"></div>
```